# how to use single html page to inject three different data in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a user profile model in Django models. I have a user_profile HTML template for the user profile page. On this profile page, I have three buttons to grab user info, all the posts created by the user, uploads made by the user respectively. I have created a profile-content CSS class that gives a section where above-mentioned user info will be published. But I don't know how to do that. I mean how can I load three different information that requires three different Django Views in the single HTML page.

views.py

```
class UserProfileView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'accounts/user_profile.html'
    model = models.UserProfile
    context_object_name = 'profile'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'username'
    slug_field = 'user__username'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserProfileView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        temp = False
        if models.Followers.objects.filter(user=context['profile'], follows=self.request.user.profile).exists():
            temp = True
        context['is_follower'] = temp
        return context
```

Comment: Why does it require three views? Why can't you do everything in that `get_context_data` method?

Comment: But userpost and user uploads view will be a list view.

Comment: But that's exactly what I asked, why do they need to be views rather than just lists?